# How do I disable the internet on a GAFE Chromebook?

Tags: chromebook

My son has been given a Chromebook and a Google Apps for Education (GAFE) account as part of a "1:1 initiative."  He has OCD and compulsively surfs the internet during school.  They have wifi.

I'd like to ask the school to disable the internet on his Chromebook, and then the teachers can temporarily enable it several times each day to get him in sync.  Or perhaps they could exchange files with a memory stick?

If there is a way to disable the internet on a Chromebook?  If so, can you give me step-by-step instructions I can forward to the school?  He doesn't normally bring the Chromebook home.  (I could have him bring it home once, specially, though, if there's a one-time procedure I should carry out myself.)

There are browser extensions that allow one to edit files in one's Google Drive while offline.

Is the memory stick an option?

[Could someone invent a tag for GAFE?  I don't have enough rep.]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling it, you can try making a whitelist with the following plugin - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-site/eiimnmioipafcokbfikbljfdeojpcgbh.